# Why "cat /dev/urandom" hung my bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using the following line to generate a random script:

```
export MY_VAR="nxf-$(cat /dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 24 | head -n 1)"
```

This works fine, but when I include it in a BASH script and I execute it, the script execution hung.

The process tree show the following processes:

```
 4045 ?        S      0:00      bash .command.run
 4046 ?        R     22:38       \_ cat /dev/urandom
 4047 ?        S      1:03       \_ tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9
 4048 ?        S      0:34       \_ fold -w 24
```

It seems that `urandom` never exit. Why this happens ?

Comment: Try http://unix.stackexchange.com/ -- StackOverflow is for programming questions, but you're asking about the behavior of an operating system.

Comment: Running it from a script works fine for me (Linux Mint 17, kernel 3.13, 64 bit; bash 4.3.11)

Comment: Actually the script is executed through a grid scheduler, thus by another daemon

Comment: You should post a minimal, reproducible example that demonstrates your problem. Because this doesn't. I can copy & paste it into script.sh, run that, and the whole pipeline terminates just fine.

Comment: I have the same problem. It happens only when it is execute by the grid daemon. It seems that urandom stream is never closed.

Comment: You are aware that `/dev/urandom` provides the illusion of an infinitely-sized file, I presume? You might do better with something more along the lines of `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1024 count=1` than `cat`...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should never use `cat` with `/dev/urandom`. Nor should you use any utilities which are designed for text files.

`/dev/urandom` is a continuous stream of random data. It will never produce an end of file. Buffered reads will fill the read buffer, so even if you are piping the output of `cat` into some other program, the read won't be terminated until the pipe is closed.

None of that would be anything other than inefficient, except that when you read `/dev/urandom`, you are using up entropy (randomness), which is a precious resource. Once entropy is used up, `/dev/urandom`'s output will be less random, which defeats the purpose. (More entropy will be collected, but it takes a while to build up.)

All of this goes double for `/dev/random`, because when it runs out of entropy, it usually blocks. (Except on OSs which make `/dev/random` a synonym for `/dev/urandom`.)

Consequently, you should always read exactly the amount of random data you need, and no more.

Apparently, you're aiming at 24 alphanumeric characters. There are 62 possible alphanumeric characters; it would simplify things greatly if you were willing to allow two other characters to bring the total to 64. In that case, you could produce 24 characters by extracting 18 bytes of randomness and passing it through a base64 encoder. To extract a precise amount of data, use `dd`, which is designed for the purpose:

```
dd bs=18 count=1 if=/dev/urandom | base64 | tr +/ _.
```

(The `tr` at the end translates the two non-alphanumeric characters produced by `base64` into two different characters which are more filename-friendly. Just a suggestion.)

If you're determined to use precisely alphanumeric characters, you could use a rejection strategy similar to the one you're currently using, but based on the above. Unfortunately, it's not possible to predict exactly how much input you'll need in this case, so the simplest approach is to read a little bit extra, and retry in the rare case that you don't get enough:

```
# Here we produce 28 characters each time
until s=$(dd bs=21 count=1 if=/dev/urandom |
           LC_ALL=C tr -cd A-Za-z0-9)
      ((${#s} >= 24)); do :; done
# When the loop ends we have at least 24 characters; truncate
s=${s:0:24}
```

If you don't have bash, you can replace `((${#s} >= 24))` with `[ ${#s} -ge 24 ]` and `s=${s:0:24}` with `s=$(printf %.24s $s)`

But if you're just trying to generate good random filenames, you should use `mktemp`, which allows you to specify a skeleton for the names, and also verifies that the generated name is not already present. See `man mktemp`.

Answer (score 12):

Actually `cat /dev/urandom` never ends on its own. But when `head -1` reads first line, it exits, thus closing stdin and closing a pipe. OS raises `SIGPIPE` to `fold` is also exits, and so on, so `cat /dev/urandom` ends eventually.

In your case, something blocking `SIGPIPE`, i.e. trap can do that:

```
$ trap '' PIPE 
$ cat /dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 24 | head -n 1
7FazO6mnsIow3ylkvEHB55jE
(hungs)
```

Try to re-enable it in subshell:

```
( trap - PIPE ; cat /dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 24 | head -n 1 )
```

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong. This is the right answer. Also, the blocked SIGPIPE was spot-on in my case :)

Comment: Unfortunately, use `trap` still leads to hanging when the command is executed on GitHub Actions. I have to explicitly close the pipe to prevent hanging: `head -80 /dev/urandom | LC_ALL=c tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1`